# Do shared links to one question/answer on multiple outside webpages all count toward the same Announcer, Booster, or Publicist badge?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, sharing, publicity-badges

If I share a link such as this one:

```
http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/40032/20394
```

to a question or answer on multiple outside webpages, are all the incoming visits to this link from *all* webpages/URLs amalgamated together to award the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges? Or are the badges awarded only for the requisite number of unique IP visits from a single originating webpage/URL?

If the latter (which I doubt), would multiple badges be awarded for gaining the requisite number of visits from each outside website/URL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes! Note that there are two numbers in the URL:

- 40032 is the post ID.
- 20394 is your user ID.

The three badges track how many people visited *your* link with the second number, and they keep an overall count that ignores which website your link was visited from<sup>1</sup>. So, no, you can only get one of each badge from each post, but yes, clicks from every source count towards the same total.

---

<sup>1: well, clicks from within the SE network don't count, but other than that.</sup>